# Poll as "Rendered Entity" field is not displaying in views

Tags: views, polls

I have integrated Poll as a field in Content type,let be "article'.Poll is displayed as rendered entity wherever required.

Now I have created a view listing all articles.Poll is also added and displayed as rendered entity.

When the poll field is called in Custom text.,Poll entity(form) is displayed in views preview,but not in Output page..In output no poll is displayed